# Extend material ui theme options using module augmentation not working with TypeText

Tags: typescript, material-ui, module-augmentation

Here is a codesandbox to reproduce the issue.
https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-sun-0zyb3?file=/src/newTheme.ts:0-401

The TypeText is not being accepted, but the SimplePaletteColorOptions is working. It's the same thing, I don't understand where I went wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a problem with export from mui/styles. It was resolved [here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/30851). So you just need to update @mui/material

Comment: Heyy.. Thanks for answering. I'm happy to say that I only made a PR for this issue. :D

Comment: Lol, I hope at least other people will fount it usefull XD